# Redirect All SSL Requests to One Domain

Tags: redirect, ssl, https

Recently, the company I work for changed their name, and therefore is changing its domain name.  Previously, we redirected all requests on port 80 of our web server to https : //www .olddomain.com, so that all pages were sent over SSL.  Now that we have changed, our SSL certificate for www. olddomain.com has expired, and we want to redirect all requests for https : //www. olddomain.com to https : //www. newdomain.com (in case anyone bookmarked us as https : //.....).

I have tried every redirection method I know, mod_rewrite, DNS forwarding, etc, but I cannot get https : //www.olddomain.com to redirect to https : //www.newdomain.com, it says that the site is untrusted.

We are running Apache 2.2 on linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should always add a literal question in your questions, at least "Is it possible to create trusted connection on above condition with some method I don't know?"

Answer (score 1):

Not to dive into unnecessary details - if certificate itself has expired, you won't be able to make trusted connection with it, browser will always warn. To make it transparent, you'd have to renew/buy valid certificate for old domain, or force any possible website user to first download, install and trust your own RootCA certificate (obviously impossible). Theoretically there are some browser-supported HTTPS protocol extensions to deal with original construction of https, but even if they were implemented it still won't "help" for outdated certificate. It is problem with certificate itself, not really with virtual server hostname / certificate common name recognition and matching for which such protocol extensions are conceptually planned/designed.

You should have been performing domain migration during time when old certificate was still valid. Have a look here [CNAME SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935229/cname-ssl-certificates) as well.