# SSL How to with dynamic dns

Tags: ssl, dns, bluehost

I've got a home server that sits behind a dynamic ip address. I use a free dynamic dns service (http://freedns.afraid.org/) so that I can access my server via the following (fake) hostname   foo.example.com

I use bluehost to host a separate domain,  mycompany.com, and used their DNS settings to set up a CNAME to route traffic for mycompany.com to foo.example.com

What i want to do now is throw an SSL cert into the mix. The problem is I don't know how to go about getting the cert.  Some companys (godaddy) want me to associate a domain to the cert.  I don't know if that's mycompany.com or foo.example.com.  Even if i pick one, it seems like the browser would complain about a mismatch.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CNAME SSL certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935229/cname-ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the website gets accessed as https://foo.example.com you need a certificate for foo.example.com. If it gets accessed as https://mycompany.com you need a certfificate for mycompany.com. If it needs to be accessed with both names (like if one side would redirect to the other) you need a certificate containing both names.

Comment: It just needs to be accessed via https://mycompany.com  I was worried that since mycompany.com has to go through (i'm not even sure that's the right term) foo.example.com, there would be some sort of error.

I'll give it a shot and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Got a cert for mycompany.com and everything was good to go! Thanks again.