# Setup SSL for a CNAME record?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, cname

I've already seen the following

> https://superuser.com/questions/685353/ssl-certificate-for-cname-record
>
> [CNAME SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935229/cname-ssl-certificates)

I have a domain, say `example1.com` for which I have purchased an SSL certificate. I have another domain `example2.com`. I want to add a CNAME record for `example1` on `example2` and enforce it to work with SSL (even if I have to purchase another certificate for `example2`)

Somewhat like:

```
NAME                |       TYPE        |            VALUE
--------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------
  sub.example2.com          CNAME           https://sub.example1.com
```

where

`sub.example1.com` already has SSL

`sub.example2.com` does not have SSL (yet)

As per what I've learnt, *SSL certificates are installed on the web server ( Apache for example ), and not on the DNS level*.

How can I setup SSL for the subdomain ???

Answer (score 0):

[multiple SSL](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)
You need to add it to your Apache conf file.